# declarations accessibillity method errors after no changes

Tags: c#, declaration

I was hoping I could ask a general question. I have a very large project that I work on daily. Today I spent most of the day working on the code ( 4+ hours). I was doing some basic debugging I stopped and re-ran the project. I was met with 15 errors about a missing partial modifier on declaration. Seems just about every designer file I have has this error. I must have changed something but I cannot imagine what it was. I have not done a check in so I may loose a lot of work. I'd like to maybe understand what this error means and see if I can't fix it.  I'm unsure what code to share as there are many files in the project, and the errors are pointing to many of these files.

this is one of the designer files where the errors occur.

it says dLCD has this error. Did the file get corrupted?

```
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "17.0.0.0")]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
internal class dLCD {
    
    private static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager resourceMan;
    
    private static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo resourceCulture;
    
    [global::System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1811:AvoidUncalledPrivateCode")]
    internal dLCD() {
    }
```

Comment: It must be something changed, check your source code control history is my advise

Comment: looks like the file that is generating errors is a file I do not have a 1 is appended to the name. My file is dLCD.Designer.cs but this file is dLCD1.Designer.cs and it says the code was generated by a tool.

Comment: @dexiang Where is the history for that?

Answer (score 0):

not sure what it was but I loaded a back up that builds, and moved in all files I touched. It worked fine after that.